# How to solve this differential equation? $xy'-y=x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve this differential equation $xy'-y=x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I tried $y=vx$ method and got an answer. But the answer is not matching with the given answer.
The answer is in the form $y=x\sinh(x+c)$.
Please help me to obtain the answer.

Comment: And what did you get?

Comment: Log(|(y/x)+√((y^2/x^2)+1)|=(x+c)

Answer (score 1):

$$y=vx \longrightarrow y' = v' x + v$$
$$x(v' x + v)-vx = x\sqrt{x^2 + v^2x^2}$$
$$v'x^2=x^2\sqrt{1+v^2}$$
$$v'=\sqrt{1+v^2}$$
$$x =\int\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}=\sinh^{-1}(y/x)+c$$
$$y=x\sinh(x +c)$$

Comment: @Raffaele - fixed, forgot the divide sign

Comment: We have to solve it by variations of parameters

Comment: @Kaushik - Please ask what you want to ask.

Comment: I am saying that the equation have to be solved by variation of parameters as written in the book.

Comment: @Kaushik - that's not what you asked in your question though, is it?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Can You please help me by solving it with variations of parameters?

Comment: So edit the question including what you expect.

Comment: I have solved it thanks @nbubis